# How to suppress warnings from stats:::regularize.values?

Tags: r, warnings

In newer versions of R (I have 3.6 and previously had 3.2), the `stats::regularize`.values function has been changed to have a default value of warn.collapsing as TRUE. This function is used in `splinefun` and several other interpolation functions in R. In a microsimulation model, I am using `splinefun` to smooth a large amount (n > 100,000) of data points of the form (x, f(x)). Here, x is a simulated vector of positive-valued scalers, and f(x) is some function of (x). With an n that large, there are often some replications of pseudo-randomly generated values (i.e., not all values of x are unique). My understanding is that `splinefun` gets rid of ties in the x values. That is not a problem for me, but, because of the new default, I get a warning message printed each time (below)

> "In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties)) :   collapsing to
>   unique 'x' values"

Is there a way to either change the default of the warn.collapsing argument of the `stats::regularize.values` function back to F? Or can I somehow suppress that particular warning? This matters because it's embedded in a long microsimulation code and when I update it I often run into bugs. So I can't just ignore warning messages.

I tried using the formalize function. I was able to get the default arguments of `stats::regularize.values` printed, but when I tried to assign new values using the `alist` function it said there is no object 'stats'.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem too, and fixed it by adding `ties=min` to the argument list of `splinefun()`.
The value of `missing(ties)` is now passed as `warn.collapsing` to `regularize.values()`.

https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/splinefun.R
https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/approx.R

Also see:
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html
and search for `regularize.values()`.

Comment: a similar strategy works for `approx` (explicitly specify `ties` argument)

Answer (score 3):

Referencing [this article](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Suppress-specific-warnings-td4664591.html)

Wrap your call of `regularize.values` like this:

```
withCallingHandlers(regularize.values(x), warning = function(w){
  if (grepl("collapsing to unique 'x' values", w$message))
   invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
})
```

Working example (adapted from the above link to call a function):

```
f1 <- function(){
  x <- 1:10
  x + 1:3
}

f1()

# if we just call f1() we get a warning
Warning in x + 1:3 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
 [1]  2  4  6  5  7  9  8 10 12 11


withCallingHandlers(f1(), warning=function(w){invokeRestart("muffleWarning")})
 [1]  2  4  6  5  7  9  8 10 12 11
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, I don't actually call the regularize.values function. It's part of the splinefun function which I use. The splinefun function's first line is to use regularize.values. However, your suggestion did give me an idea. What I ended up doing was using the fix function to change the last argument in the regularize.values call (from 'missing(ties)' to 'F') within the splinefun function code. However, adjusting the code in functions like this makes me nervous.